# Change model value to None in Query set by checking a field value inside it from Manager

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a Manager fucntion that prefetches cover photo of the model. the **cover_photo** (Foreign key to CoverPhoto) model has a field `is_verified`. Is there a way to make the cover_photo object `None` if it has `is_verified=False` from the manager? So that from normal user point view I can hide unverified photos but still need other things and from admin side I can see all photos in List get query.

```
   return self.prefetch_related(
       Prefetch(
           "deity_list",
           queryset=Deity.objects.select_related("cover_photo")
           .filter(is_verified=True, site_visible=True),
       ),
   )
```

**What did I tried:** *I tried to change the object before it returns, but the change is not affected the returning* `objs`. *However when I debugged, I found the change did happened till* `deity_obj` *that gets from second* `for` *loop.*

```
objs = self.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "deity_list",
        queryset=Deity.objects.select_related("cover_photo")
        .filter(is_verified=True, site_visible=True),
        to_attr="deities_list",
    ),
)
for obj in objs:
    for deity_obj in obj.deities_list:
        if not deity_obj.cover_photo.is_verified:
            deity_obj.cover_photo = None

return objs
```

This wouldn't be the way to solve the issue, but this far is I can go with my learnings. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Rather passing the `cover_photo` field directly, I made a property and made the checking inside it and returned the field or None respectively. And seriealized that property instead the field. I couldn't find a way through Manager.